# jquery .slideToggle pushes content up

Tags: jquery

I have some divs that I want to show/hide with .slideToggle.  I expect .slideToggle to always push content down when it expands, and pull up content from below when it contracts.

But it seems to push content up and/or scroll down when it expands, causing a jumpy animation.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/photocurio/X785b/

```
$('.milford-directions').click(function() {
  $('#milford').slideToggle();
});
$('.tufts-directions').click(function() {
  $('#tufts').slideToggle();
});
$('.our-affiliations').click(function() {
  $('#affiliations').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: That's because you're clicking on named anchor links, and the default behavior for that is to bring the target to the top of the viewport. You can fix that by using `.preventDefault()`: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/X785b/6/

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have the ID as the anchor href. By default, when clicking on an anchor with an ID as the href, the page will scroll to that ID.

Take a look when I remove the ID: http://jsfiddle.net/X785b/5/

```
<a class="our-affiliations directions">FIRST BOX</a></p>
```

You can fix this by using `preventDefault` or `return false`

http://jsfiddle.net/X785b/7/

Comment: Thanks. And I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little better

http://jsfiddle.net/X785b/3/

JQUERY

```
$('.our-affiliations').click(function() {
    $('#affiliations').slideToggle();
    return false;
});

$('.tufts-directions').click(function() {
    $('#tufts').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
$('.milford-directions').click(function() {
    $('#milford').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

and return false on the button click stops the link jumping around to the ID of the div specified in the href.